# When is the object locked while recompiling in oracle

Tags: oracle, stored-procedures, locking

Please help me in understanding the concept.

I was trying to compile an invalid package from a procedure using the below code. It was throwing following error

> ORA-04021: timeout occurred while waiting to lock object

```
for cur_rec in (select   object_name, object_type
                from   user_objects
                where  object_type in ('PACKAGE', 'PROCEDURE', 'FUNCTION','PACKAGE BODY')
                and    status != 'VALID')
loop
  begin
    if cur_rec.object_type != 'PACKAGE BODY' then          
      execute immediate 'ALTER '||cur_rec.object_type||' usr.'||cur_rec.object_name||' COMPILE';
    else
      execute immediate 'ALTER PACKAGE usr.'||cur_rec.object_name||' COMPILE BODY';
      dbms_output.put_line('Package recompiling finish');
    end if;

  end;
end loop;
```

I have seen all the suggestions in this website. I checked sessions browser, but there are no other active sessions referring this package.

So checked dba_dependencies and realized the procedure from which the package is being recompiled is referencing a table that is also used in package. But this table access in the procedure comes after recompiling package (In other words there is a select query fired on a table tht is being used in procedure and package as well)

Please help me guys, is this the reason for the error? Would you think alter session . reset package instead of above code would work or throw the same error?

Answer (score 1):

If this is running inside a procedure, won't it try to recompile itself and deadlock because it is currently running?

The same sort of deadlock will occur if you have a procedure try to delete itself:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PROCEDURE calc_bonus (emp_id NUMBER) AS
BEGIN
   EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'DROP PROCEDURE calc_bonus'; -- deadlock!
END;
/
```

Comment: Hallo Michael, thanks for your response. I'm recompiling package from another procedure which is an external one. To my knowledge I'm sure there will be no deadlock in this situation.  But my question was:   the procedure from which the package is being recompiled is referencing a table that is also used in package. But this table access in the procedure comes after recompiling package line (to be more clear: there is a select query fired on a table tht is being used in procedure and package as well).  Due to this can there be a deadlock?

Comment: I wouldn't think so as a recompile does not execute a query where a data access deadlock might occur - it just resolves al the references, parses and validates all the code etc.

Comment: I should also note that most people don't try to walk the dependency tree to figure out what to recompile anymore - they just use the Oracle built-ins like: dbms_utility.compile_schema(your_user, false); to recompile all invalid objects in schema your_user.

Comment: yeah you are right, but I have some procedures with errors, so I didn't want the entire schema to be recompiled. I used where clause in my query to restrict to only the packages or procedures I need to recompile.

Comment: Actually I had an invalid package error. So inorder to get rid of that error I'm recompiling. But still I get some other error. May be its better i use reset package and reinitialise my package variables or can you suggest me some other method.